# Disk Brakes on Nishiki Pueblo

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a Nishiki Pueblo and I am looking to put disk brakes on it.

My problem is that I am not sure which disk brakes fit on my bike.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not possible/cost effective to put disk brakes on your bike. If you need help getting your current brakes working better, ask another question.  V-Brakes can work very well when adjusted properly.  Some bikes are sold with brakes made out of very low end materials, a simple upgrade of the v-brakes may increase braking performance quite a bit.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @paul. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and read [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

for what I see online about your bike, you don't have fitting for disc brakes.
You could upgrade to better V brakes, or Cantilever brakes, even idraulic Magura rim brakes, if power is what you are looking for, but disc brakes won't fit on your frame.